# NullPointerException in Guice binding. Am I binding HelperFactory incorrectly?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Here is the following code, where I am getting a NullPointerException. HelperFactory is a Client class, which I cannot change. I am new to Guice, and going through the documentation did not help in understanding where I am going wrong.

```
    public class ModuleA extends AbstractModule {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
           super.configure();
           bind(HelperFactory.class).toInstance(HelperFactory.getInstance());
         
           @Provides
           public DoSomethingClient getDoSomethingClient() {
               return DoSomethingClient.getInstance();
           }
        }   
    }
 
   
    class DoSomethingClient {
       public static DoSomethingClient getInstance() {
          var helperFactory = HelperFactory.getInstance();
          return new DoSomethingClient(helperFactory.getClient());
       }
    }
```

```
Stack Trace:
    Error in custom provider, java.lang.NullPointerException
      at com.myApp.abc.injection.ModuleA.DoSomethingClient(ModuleA.java:22)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that you are using Guice in a wrong way. Or there is not enough information on this ticket to say anything.

But, it seems like the issue is not related to Guice.

Which exact line in this code is throwing you a Nullpointer?

is it
`return new DoSomethingClient(helperFactory.getClient());` ?

if that is the case, `HelperFactory.getInstance();` did not return any object. You might want to ask why is that `null` ? Well, Guice is not instantiating that object anywhere. So, whichever the code that is instantiating and setting that object in the `HelperFactory` is probably not invoked yet.